# find the minimum length of vector in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How can I find it out in pure vectors method?the answer is 5-√7

> Let $|\overrightarrow{OA}| = 2$, $|\overrightarrow{OB}| = 6$ and $|\overrightarrow{OC}| = 2$ such that the angles between $\overrightarrow{OA}$, $\overrightarrow{OB}$ and $\overrightarrow{OC}$ are $60^\circ$, where $O$ is the origin. It is given that $\overrightarrow{OX}$ and $\overrightarrow{OY}$ be two vectors such that $\overrightarrow{OY} \cdot (\overrightarrow{OY} + \overrightarrow{BA}) = 0$ and $\overrightarrow{OX} \cdot \overrightarrow{OC} = 12$. Find the minimum value of $|\overrightarrow{XY}|$.

That is my work but I think I'm in the wrong direction

> $\overrightarrow{OY} \cdot (\overrightarrow{OY} + \overrightarrow{BA}) = 0
> ⇒ |\overrightarrow{OY}|=2√7cos(β)$

> $\overrightarrow{OX} \cdot \overrightarrow{OC} = 12$ ⇒ $|\overrightarrow{OX}|=2/cos(α)$

> $|\overrightarrow{XY}|²=|\overrightarrow{OX}|²+|\overrightarrow{OY}|²-2|\overrightarrow{OX}||\overrightarrow{OY}|cos(θ)$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151321/discussion-on-question-by-tll-find-the-minimum-length-of-vector-in-bbb-r3); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking $A = (2, 0, 0) , C = (1, \sqrt{3}, 0), B = (3, \sqrt{3}, 2 \sqrt{6} ) $

Then $A,B,C$ satisfy all the given data on $A,B,C$, namely $|A| = |C | = 2 $ and $|B| = 6 $.  In addition, $\angle AOB = \angle AOC = \angle BOC = 60^\circ$.

Now point $X$ satisfies $C \cdot X = 12 $ and this is an equation of a plane, while $Y$ satisfies

$Y \cdot (Y + BA) = 0 $

To figure out what this surface is, complete the square in $Y$ in this equation.  Note that

$ Y \cdot (Y + BA) = (Y + \dfrac{1}{2} BA ) \cdot (Y + \dfrac{1}{2} BA) - \dfrac{1}{4} (BA) \cdot (BA) $

Since this quantity is equal to zero, then

$(Y + \dfrac{1}{2} BA ) \cdot (Y + \dfrac{1}{2} BA) = \dfrac{1}{4} (BA) \cdot (BA) $

This can be written as,

$ (Y - (- \dfrac{1}{2} BA) ) \cdot (Y - (- \dfrac{1}{2} BA) ) = r^2 $

i.e.

$ (Y - S) \cdot (Y - S) = r^2 \tag{*} $

where $S = - \dfrac{1}{2} BA $

and $r^2 = \dfrac{1}{4} (BA) \cdot (BA) $, i.e.

$r = \dfrac{1}{2} \| BA \| $

Equation $(*)$ is an equation of a sphere with the center of this sphere being the point $ S = - \dfrac{1}{2} B A $, and radius $r$.

Now,

$ S = - \dfrac{1}{2} BA = \dfrac{1}{2} AB = \dfrac{1}{2} ( 1 , \sqrt{3}, 2 \sqrt{6}) = ( \dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \sqrt{6}) $

The plane $C \cdot X = 12 $ passes through

$ X_1 = \dfrac{ 12 C }{C \cdot C} = \dfrac{ 12 (1, \sqrt{3}, 0) }{4} = (3, 3\sqrt{3}, 0)$

Its equation is $ C \cdot (X - X_1) = 0 $

Therefore the distance between the center of the sphere and this plane is

$ d = \dfrac{ | C \cdot ( S - X_1) | }{\sqrt{C \cdot C} } = \dfrac{ | (1, \sqrt{3}, 0) \cdot ( -2.5, -2.5 \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{6} ) }{2} = 5 $

The radius of the sphere is $r = \dfrac{1}{2} \| {BA} \| =  \| S \| =\dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{28} = \sqrt{7} $

Hence, the minimum distance between $X$ and $Y$ is

$ \large \boxed{\overline{XY}_{Min} =  5 - \sqrt{7}} $

Comment: can you explain more about why this is an equation of a sphere and the step?

Comment: This follows by completing the square.  You see $ Y \cdot (Y + V) = (Y + \dfrac{1}{2} V) \cdot ( Y + \dfrac{1}{2} V) - \dfrac{1}{4} V \cdot V = 0 $,  hence $$ (Y + \dfrac{1}{2} V ) \cdot (Y + \dfrac{1}{2} V) = R^2 $$ where $ R^2 = \dfrac{1}{4} V \cdot V $

Comment: I can't fully understand, 1/2 BA is not started at origin,how come it can be the center?

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{2} BA $ is just a vector with $x,y,z$ components.  The given equation of the sphere describes the $x,y,z$ components of the tip of vector $\vec{OY}$ which is the point $Y$.

Comment: Can you give me materials that introduce this equation and proof?

Comment: Sorry. I don't have any supporting materials.  The proof is ,as I commented above, by completing the square.

Comment: I Can understand the following message but I don't know how can I connect your word to this explain. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-equation-of-a-circle-in-vector-form-at-a-point-other-than-its-origin-What-is-the-center-and-radii/answer/Gopal-Menon-15?ch=15&oid=188595273&share=6e4def75&srid=hLgOBU&target_type=answer

Comment: How come 1/2BA is same to vector c that he explains?

Comment: Are you here???

Comment: I am sorry, I can't explain my solution any clearer than I did.

Comment: so Why do you think that 1/2BA is the centre

Comment: @TLL I've updated and edited my solution to make this point you're asking about clearer.  If you still have questions, I'll more than happy to answer them.

Comment: I solved my confused part. Thank for sharing

Comment: @TLL You're welcome.

Comment: how about the X1,what equation is?

Comment: Just substitute the X1 into the given plane equation.  You'll see that it satisfies the equation.

Comment: but why do you think that 12 C/C•C can satisfy the equation

Comment: Because $$C \cdot \left( \dfrac {12 C}{  C \cdot C} \right) = 12 \left( \dfrac{ C \cdot C }{C \cdot C} \right) =12$$